# Divide dataframe column by column from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes that look similar and I want to divide one column from `df1` by a column from `df2`.

Some sample data is below:

```
dict1 = {'category': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 1.0},
 'Id': {0: 24108, 1: 24307, 2: 24307, 3: 24411, 4: 24411},
 'count': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 33, 3: 98, 4: 33}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

dict2 = {'Id': {0: 24108, 1: 24307, 2: 24411},
 'count': {0: 3, 1: 35, 2: 131}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

I am trying to create a new column in the first dataframe (`df1`) called `weights` by dividing `df1['count']` by `df2['count']`. Except for the column `category` and `count` in both dfs, the values are identical in the other columns.

I have the following piece of code, but I cannot seem to understand where the error is:

```
df1['weights'] = (df1['count']
                      .div(df1.merge(df2, on = 'Id', how = 'left')
                           ['count'].to_numpy())
                      )
```

I get the following error when I run the code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'count'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_354/1318629977.py in <module>
      1 complete['weights'] = (complete['count']
----> 2                       .div(complete.merge(totals, on = 'companyId', how = 'left')['count'].to_numpy())
      3                       )
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: There's `count_x` and `count_y` after your merge not count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you end up with `count_x` and `count_y` after your merge, you need to specify which one you want:

```
df1['weights'] = (df1['count'].div(df1.merge(df2, on = 'Id', how = 'left')['count_y'].to_numpy()))
```

Comment: The best way would be to merge without creating these extra columns since they are identical.

Comment: @NelsonGon `count_x` and `count_y` are not identical in terms of values.